# ImportError: cannot import name IRCBot

Tags: python, import, importerror, irc

I'm importing a module and its all done in the same file:

```
from irc import IRCBot, run_bot

class greeterBot(IRCBot):
    def greet(self, nick, messege, channel):
        return 'Hi %s' % nick

    def command_patterns(self):
        return (
            self.ping('^hello', self.greet),
            )
host = "coolwhizserver"
port = 6667
nick = 'Alfred'

run_bot(greeterBot, host, port, nick ['#randomchannel'])
```

This is the code, I'll print the output below:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Greeter.py", line 1, in <module>
    from irc import IRCBot, run_bot
ImportError: cannot import name IRCBot`

Comment: the irc modul is missing search it with pip  "pip search IRCBot"

Comment: pip is a package management system

Answer (score 0):

Please check what version you have - If you have 32-bits version of package and 64-bits version of Python (or reverse situation) then the import never running .

Comment: when I enter:
    python-32 -c 'import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))'
into Terminal it returns:
32

presumably that means Im running 32 bit.
What does that mean?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow.  It would be helpful if you gave a more detailed answer, like describing how to check python's bit size, as well as the package's bit size.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that python can't find the class named  IRCbot inside irc.
Do you have irc installed? If so, ypu could try to do

from irc.bot import IRCBot

If you don't have irc installed you can install it with pip:

pip install irc

What version of python are you using?

Comment: Adding .bot didn't do the trick. I have got irc installed though.
Im using Python 2.7.10

Comment: I see on http://irckit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-with-pip that you need irckit installed.